# Llama2 Vocab contents

Tags: llm, llama-2, token

since, Llama2 is multi lingual model and it supports multiple languages, including English, Spanish, French, German, Italian, Portuguese, and Dutch. Vocab Size of Llama is 32K. How to know out of 32k vocab tokens, what percent of tokens belong to English and other languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to know out of 32k vocab tokens, what percent of tokens belong to English and other languages?

Tokens in Llama aren't words but subwords, since the Llama tokenizer uses [Byte-Pair Encoding (BPE)](https://huggingface.co/learn/nlp-course/chapter6/5?fw=pt). Therefore a token in Llama is typically not specific to a language.

Comment: isn't it like subwords are language specific. Eg Word: 'Tokenization', subwords could be 'Token' and 'ization' and thus they are English language specific?

Comment: @VinaySharma some might but I don't know the percentage. I'm guessing it's rather low since there exist many languages, eg see https://huggingface.co/datasets/uonlp/CulturaX for a list of languages in a similar dataset